# Rails - How to Perform Fuzzy Search on Multiple Tables using Textacular?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, fuzzy-search

I am using the [textacular](https://github.com/textacular/textacular) gem to implement fuzzy search in my Rails application, and I cannot figure out how to perform a search on multiple tables at once. Here's an example query that searches multiple tables WITHOUT `textacular`:

```
@results = Owner.includes(:car => :company).where("name LIKE ? OR cars.name LIKE ? OR companies.name LIKE ?", sql_query, sql_query, sql_query).references(:cars, :companies)
```

As you can see, this query searches the `Owner`, `Car`, and `Company` tables. The farthest I got with `textacular` is this:

```
@results = Owner.includes(:car => :company).references(:cars, :companies).fuzzy_search({name: sql_query})
```

The above query only searches the `Owner` table, though. I've tried doing the following to get it to search the `Companies` table as well:

```
@results = Owner.includes(:car => :company).references(:cars, :companies).fuzzy_search({name: sql_query, "companies.name" => sql_query})
```

This doesn't work because it tries searching the `owners.companies.name` field, which of course does not exist. I want it to search the `companies.name` field in addition to the `owners.name` field. Does anyone know how to perform a fuzzy search on multiple tables using `textacular`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out! You need to add the joined table name as a nested hash. Let's say I want to search by the `name` fields of the `Owner` model AND the `Car` model:

```
@results = Owner.includes(:car).references(:cars).fuzzy_search({name: sql_query, cars: { name: sql_query}})
```

The `cars` table specified in the `fuzzy_search` method refers to the name of the table, NOT the name of the association.

I got inspiration from this old [Rails commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/cd994eff9a343df376bfaec59de5b24a2ab51256) from 2008, which made me realize that the conditions you can use in any standard Rails query are available in the `fuzzy_search` method.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're wedded to textacular but from their docs it looks like you can only search by one model.

I've used [PgSearch](https://github.com/Casecommons/pg_search) before and and it's pretty robust, you can search across models.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I was actually typing up my answer as you posted this. I figured out how to do it.